# Why is Qt screaming German at me?

Tags: c++, qt

> Modul "QtQuick.Controls" ist nicht installiert

I don't really speak German and I'm kind of wondering if anybody knows why the Qt debug output starts out in English, but switches to German, resulting in a message like the one above.

I've searched all of my files for `German` and `DE` and the like with no success.

I've searched the net and Stack Overflow but I seem to be the only one with this issue.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional.

Can anybody tell me why the switch to German happened and/or how to change it back to English?

Comment: Screaming? Yeah I guess that's what we Germans do. Maybe turn off your speakers. (Or write code that doesn't need debugging :-))

Comment: @Jens DBZ Abridged reference.  I couldn't help myself.  :)

Comment: QtQuick is a module for Germans only, all others do UI hard way.

Comment: What OS are you on? Might check the system locale settings to see if it got set to German by accident.

Comment: Check if you are not calling QLocale::setDefault or something esoteric a such,

Comment: @c-smile Checked for QLocale and didn't find anything.  Would have been nice if it had been something so simple.  :(  I'm actually looking through the git diff history to see what has changed now.  Maybe I'll find something there.

Comment: I don't speak German either but it seems to be saying the module is not installed so maybe the translations got lost with the rest of the QtQuick.Controls module... What you're getting could be the default string

Comment: It could also very well be that you have messed up your application's static QLocale by writing to a stray pointer somewhere in your code. *Purify* or *valgrind* might be an option. On the other hand, learning German wouldn't necessarily be the worst thing to do. At least it might be a challenge ;)

Comment: What is the program you're trying to run? More information about the application might give us a hint.

Comment: @mindriot Not much to report about the application.  It started when I added some code to show a line graph using ChartView.  I also changed from a QGuiApplication to a QApplication.  This is why I'm so perplexed.  Two trivial changes and in the middle of execution the Qt debug output is German.  Even removing the offending code doesn't help so what tofro and Jarra McIntyre said might be it.

Comment: @soulsabr Yes, sounds like it. I guess it would be worth trying to build your application using a different Qt version, or even a different Linux distribution (if you're on Linux), to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @mindriot  Good suggestion.  I'll get a coworker to do a clean install.  If that comes out all english I'll just nuke everything Qt related on my system and reinstall.

Comment: Well, I can't figure out what has happened.  I restored the code from our git repository, added the problem code back in, and no more German.  Errors that vanish like this bug me but what can I do?  Thank you all for your suggestions.  I wish I had a concrete answer to give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely the QT QTBUG-48946 "windeployqt accumulates locales when translating", see:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48946

this affects for example also wireshark, see:

https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11619

Comment: This could very well explain the unexplained switch to German.  Anyhow, a bug is much more reasonable than yet another Monty Python sketch at winning tennis.